# rails find by path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Maybe I'm not searching on the right keywords but: Is it possible to search given an object path?

I have '/businesses/2' and I'd simply like to do something like @object = Business.find('/businesses/2') to fetch that object

One way is to:

```
ids = params[:who_id].split('/')
@object = ids[1].singularize.constantize.find(ids[2])
```

But I'm wondering if there is a built in way since this seemed to me as something quite normal to do.

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: It's polymorphic related, I have various objects that can be: say "askable", when I create a new question I provide a drop down of objects which the user can ask this question to, my drop down has the values of the object paths (ie 'Business/2', 'SomeObject/4'...), and this is what I return via ajax to create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the `id` will be the last in the string then you can split the string by `"/"` and take the last element. If you're unsure, you may use `regexp`.

If you want also to perform a search depending on what's in your string (you do not know class name)) then use `regexp` to match a model name and then use these helpers:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html
to get a name of the class.

Like:

```
klass = _yor_extracted_string.singularize.constantize
object = klass.find(_id_here_)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I know how to do this, I was wondering if there was a built in way to do it instead of using helpers from Inflector. It's looking like I'm going to use this since I've found nothing built in that does it. Thanks.